# Why can't I close and re-open react-native debug on ios device?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

So I'm building an app in react-native, both ios and android build onto devices, android with react-native run-android, and ios by going through xcode and building it that way, however when I put the ios version on an iphone, unplug it then close and try to re-open the app it goes to the load screen and then closes with out an error, just wondering if anyone has ran into this problem and has a solution, when I close the application and re-open on android it works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by putting in an iOS version?

Comment: I think you application needs metro instance for mobile also. that's why it closes itself .

Comment: I mean when building the application onto an ios device it works until I close it, but if I try to re-open it then it opens the loading screen then closes with out errors. Najam, so I would need to react-native run-ios? instead of running through xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are building a release version of the app, which bundles the js and installs/runs it locally, your debug versions of the app will require a packager to run.

Usually its easiest to leave the device connected to your computer while you do your testing, but if you are on the same wifi network, your phone and your computer, you can unplug and connect to the packager over wifi.

That being said, I've found connecting to the packager over wifi to be spotty and not worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks yeah I figured thats what was happening, due to the nature of what I'm making I ended up having to build the release version in order to test.